# python can't be started from pycharm windows terminal without full path

Tags: python, cmd, path, environment-variables, python-os

I can start python from windows cmd just typing "python", but it doesn't work from pycharm terminal - it writes, that "python" is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file.
So, `os.system('python file.py')` or `os.popen('python file.py')` also doesn't work, but I have to start another python program in my project. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add python to the windows `PATH` variable. you can find the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Comment: They say they can start python from the windows cmd prompt by writing python, that means it is there in the system variables

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is the `sys` module, that has the `exexutable` variable, that is the path to python.exe, so I'll use the full path. This solved the problem on my computer, so, I think, this will work on other computers.